# Add extension to all files in a folder using PHP

Tags: php

I have a list of files which have no extensions at all. How do I add a common extension to them all?

```
<?php

$dir='./asset/';
$col=preg_grep( '@^((?!webm).)*$@i', glob( $dir . '*' ) );

array_walk( $col , function($f){
    rename( $f, $f.'.webm' );
});

?>
```

I am trying to do this, but this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add, the following code should works, but it is not for changing extentions.

```php
array_map(
    fn ($item) => if(
        is_file("{$dir}/{$item}"
    ) rename("{$dir}/{$item}", "{$dir}/{$item}.php"),
    array_diff(scandir($dir), ['.', '..'])
);
```

Comment: I am sorry, if it is not for changing extensions, what is it for?

Comment: It's adding extention as you asked in the title.

Comment: is this php? I am getting an error - ```syntax error, unexpected token "if"```